# Differentiation of two Unix_Timestamp references

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "powerpro" including "power" data recorded in every minute of the day as following : (assume one month records including)

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      date_time      | phase_1_power | phase_2_power | phase_3_power |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2014/12/01 00:00:00 | 73.0767       | -68.2627      | -73.0767      |
| 2014/12/01 00:01:00 | 73.0293       | -68.3134      | -73.0293      |
| 2014/12/01 00:02:00 | 72.9819       | -68.3641      | -72.9819      |
| 2014/12/01 00:03:00 | 72.9345       | -68.4148      | -72.9345      |
| 2014/12/01 00:04:00 | 72.8871       | -68.4655      | -72.8871      |
| 2014/12/02 00:00:00 | 72.8397       | -68.5162      | -72.8397      |
| 2014/12/02 00:01:00 | 72.7923       | -68.5669      | -72.7923      |
| 2014/12/02 00:02:00 | 72.7449       | -68.6176      | -72.7449      |
| 2014/12/02 00:03:00 | 72.6975       | -68.6683      | -72.6975      |
| 2014/12/02 00:04:00 | 72.6501       | -68.7119      | -72.6501      |
| 2014/12/03 00:00:00 | 72.6027       | -68.7697      | -72.6027      |
| 2014/12/03 00:01:00 | 72.5553       | -68.8204      | -72.5553      |
| 2014/12/03 00:02:00 | 72.5079       | -68.8711      | -72.5079      |
| 2014/12/03 00:03:00 | 72.4605       | -68.9218      | -72.4605      |
| 2014/12/03 00:04:00 | 72.4131       | -68.9725      | -72.4131      |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to get the balance of 
End time UNIX_TIMESTAMP()value -start time UNIX_TIMESTAMP() value AND
End time = start time UNIX_TIMESTAMP() value + UNIX_TIMESTAMP() value of next 7th date

I tried this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) AS time_reff, a1.phase_1_power AS ph1,  a1.phase_2_power AS ph2,  a1.phase_3_power AS ph3
FROM powerpro a1

JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY  date_time
    )a2 ON a1.date_time = a2.min

JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY date_time
       ) a3 ON a1.date_time = a3.time - INTERVAL 7 DAY 

WHERE a1.date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY a1.date_time
```

But only got empty result.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `WHERE` part: it restricts your result set to only those entries that have start date within 7 days from `NOW()`. At the same time, because of the `JOIN`s, you only output pairs of start time - end time that are spaced by 7 days. In combination, that means that the only row that can be output is the one where end time is `NOW()` and start time is `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`.

When you delete `WHERE` part, you will be getting all pairs of start time - end time that are spaced by 7 days.

UPDATE 1:

Since this still doesn't work, let's try to rebuild this query piece-by-piece.

First try this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
```

That should give earliest timestamp for each day.

UPDATE 2:

Now try:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) AS time_reff, a1.phase_1_power AS ph1,  a1.phase_2_power AS ph2,  a1.phase_3_power AS ph3
FROM powerpro a1

JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    )a2 ON time_reff = a2.min
```

That should give all phases for the earliest timestamp for each day.

UPDATE 3:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) AS time_reff, a1.phase_1_power AS ph1,  a1.phase_2_power AS ph2,  a1.phase_3_power AS ph3
FROM powerpro a1

JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    )a2 ON UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) = a2.min

JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    )a3 ON CAST(a1.date_time AS DATETIME) = DATE_SUB(a3.time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

UPDATE 4:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) AS time_reff, a1.phase_1_power AS ph1,  a1.phase_2_power AS ph2,  a1.phase_3_power AS ph3
FROM powerpro a1
JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    )a2 ON UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) = a2.min
JOIN (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) time, MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)) AS min 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    )a3 ON UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.date_time) = a3.min - 86400
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67280/discussion-on-answer-by-striving-coder-differentiation-of-two-unix-timestamp-ref).